# How to List candidate word

Tags: c#

I have a string list

```
abc 
abb 
acc 
acb 
zx 
zxc 
zxx 
caa 
cba 
ccc
```

I want to enter 'a' I can list abb abc acb acc azx

Enter 'z'  zx zxc zxx

Enter 'c'  caa cba ccc

Enter 'ab' abb abc ab

Enter 'zx' zx zxc zxx

Somewhat like the search engine a candidate word list

But it will show the candidate according to the order of words in English
How to do that?

Comment: What is the logic? Where is your code?

Comment: `ab - caa be`. How did this happen? `caa` doesn't contain `ab`, and there is no `be` element at all.

Comment: Sorry my mistake enter D:

Comment: And I'm sorry, I did not have code, because I do not know where to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with this:

```
 List<string> strings = new List<string>()
{
    "abc", 
    "abb", 
    "acc", 
    "acb", 
    "zx",
    "zxc", 
    "zxx", 
    "caa", 
    "cba", 
    "ccc",
};
string input = "ab";// <= or whatever
foreach (string foundString in strings)
{
    if (foundString.StartsWith(input))
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine(foundString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I try to be listed after the discovery of ab abc abb acc caa cba

Comment: if input 'ab', the program will list the 'abc abb acc caa cba', I want to list 'abc abb', not a or b